# How to set alignment and field length

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a SQL Server stored procedure as below. In C# code I call this stored procedure to save it as txt file.

The problems are:

1. the output not as what I want. I want the output for each column being start with left alignment
2. each column has a specific length as what I already set in stored procedure... but it looks like not working much

Code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AR_Ebill_claim]
(
    @compcode varchar(15),
    @dateFrom smalldatetime,
    @dateTo smalldatetime,
    @episType varchar (10),
    @debtorCode varchar(30)
)
AS
    SELECT  
        CAST(ProviderCode AS VARCHAR(30)),
        CAST(MRN AS VARCHAR(25)),
        CAST(PatName AS VARCHAR(50)),
        CAST(PatNewIC AS VARCHAR(14)),
        CAST(PatOldIC AS VARCHAR(10)),
        CAST(PatID AS VARCHAR(14)),
        CAST(RefNo AS VARCHAR(15)),
        CAST(InvNo AS VARCHAR(15)),
        (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, InvDate, 103)) AS InvDate,
        CAST(BillType AS VARCHAR(2)),
        CAST(SvcType AS VARCHAR(2)),
        (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, RegDate,103)) AS RegDate,
        (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DischgDate,103)) AS DischgDate,
        CAST(ClaimAmt AS MONEY),
        --sum(PayableAmount),
        --SUM(AllocationAmount),
        PayableAmount           
    FROM
        AR_Ebilling
    WHERE
        Company = @compcode 
        AND InvDate BETWEEN @dateFrom AND DATEADD(DAY,1, @dateTo) 
        AND BillType = @episType 
        AND DebtorCode = @debtorCode 
        AND paramsourcecode = 'pb'
        AND transtype = 'in'
        AND status = 0
```

Comment: 1. Change `varchar` to `char` for a fixed length text column.  2. How do you format the text file? I'm guessing it's done in the c# code.

Comment: the alignment should be done in your C# app not in the SQL query

Comment: i code it in c# to save is as txt format

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your requirement fully.  If you assume that you would be getting column size in your dataset because you have used CAST, it may not work.  CAST would be applied when your query is built and may not transfer same size to your final output metadata.

1. Try this, which might work - Have temporary table with the size definition that you want.  Push your select statements into Temporary table.  Do select * from temporary table.
2. I am not sure whether you want this, but try - If you want standard size like ProviderCode to occupy 30 characters even if the value is 10 characters, by having trailing white spaces at the end,

   ==> Left(Cast(ProviderCode as varchar(30)) + "                              ", 30) - Just concatenate 30 characters and take left of 30 - to ensure you get fixed length.

Please share more clear, specific information if you want more details.